# How to add an eye icon in password field to show & hide password in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, slim

My code:

```
div.form-group.col-md-12
              label =t('.password')
              = f.text_field :password,
                      required: true,
                      label: false,
                      type: 'password',
                      placeholder: 'Password',
                      input_html: {autocomplete: "new-password"},
                      class: 'form-control input-sm form-control-sm'
```

This form field is for taking input of password. I want to add an eye button in the right side of the input field box which will toggle password show & hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $("body").on('click', '.toggle-password', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
      var input = $("#pass_log_id");
      if (input.attr("type") === "password") {
        input.attr("type", "text");
      } else {
        input.attr("type", "password");
      }
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field_icon toggle-password">Show/Hide</span>
<input type="password" id="pass_log_id"/>
```

=> behalf of html you can use this code

```
%script{:src => "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"}
%span.fa.fa-fw.fa-eye.field_icon.toggle-password{:toggle => "#password-field"} Show/Hide
%input#pass_log_id{:type => "password"}/
```

Comment: That's works but it comes with a new box and eye button isn't appearing

Comment: for that you need to apply icons behalf of Show/Hide

Comment: I'm new in this. Can you help regarding this by providing the code?